# Set ffmpeg path in supervsiorctl config file

Tags: python, deployment, virtualenv, supervisord

I am having a issue where my code works fine when not under supervisor.  But when under supervisor for some reason it is not finding the path to the ffmpeg dependency.

```
(env)root@www:/home/www/yout# which ffmpeg
/usr/bin/ffmpeg
```

Is there any way to set the path to ffmpeg to have it check this?

Here is my config file

```
[program:worker]
directory=/home/www/yout
environment=PATH="/home/www/env/bin"
command=python worker.py high normal low
process_name=%(program_name)s
numprocs=1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopsignal=TERM
user=root
stopsignal=TERM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ln /usr/bin/ffmpeg /home/www/env/bin/ffmpeg
```

will create a link in a folder already in the workers PATH, alternatively you could add /usr/bin to the workers PATH

eg

```
environment=PATH="/home/www/env/bin:/usr/bin"
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  This has been a few days to get it down to this exact issue.

Comment: Could you explain more? I have the same problem where I always get `FATAL     can't find command '/usr/bin/ffmpeg -loglevel` when I run a ffmpeg process by using supervisor, any explanation of how to solve it?